# Kendo MVC Treeview get all checked nodes and pass them to the Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

First time with MVC5 and Telerik... I am reading Active Directory and getting all the security groups to display in a TreeView. After an Admin is done selecting the Roles he/she shall press the Save Groups button and then the javascript is supposed to get all nodes and pass them to the controller. The controller will save to the database. I need to know how to access the datacontext for a given node. After I get the data context I can proceed to get all of the nodes context and pass it to the controller.

**Kendo Treeview and Buttons:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Configure";
}
@model IEnumerable<CMDB.Web.Models.AdminGroups>

<div>
    <input id="save" type="button" value="Save Groups" onclick="SaveData()" />
    <input id="return" type="button" value="Return" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Admin")'" />

    @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeview")
        .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
            .Name("checkedFiles")
            .CheckChildren(true)
        )
        .Events(events => events.Check("onCheck"))
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .AutoScroll(true)
        .DataSource(source => source
            .Model(model => model.Id("id").HasChildren("hasChildren"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetActiveDircetoryGroups", "Configure"))
        )
    )
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    //show checked node IDs on datasource change
    function onCheck() {
        var treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    var id = treeView.dataItem(e.node);
    }

function SaveData() {

    var AllSelectedNodes = new Array();
    AllSelectedNodes = ($("#treeview .k-item input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest(".k-item"));
    alert(AllSelectedNodes.join('\n'));
    var myApiUrl = '@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultAPI", new { controller = "AdminValues", action = "SaveSelectedAdmins"})';
    var movies = $.ajax({
            url: myApiUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: AllSelectedNodes
    });
    }

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveSelectedAdmins(IEnumerable<CMDB.Web.Models.AdminGroups> ag)
{
    string Sids = string.Empty;
    foreach (var s in ag)
    {
        var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "", "");//blank for security purposes
        GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Guid, s.id.Value.ToString());
        if (s.id.Value.ToString() == gp.Guid.Value.ToString())
        {
            Sids = Sids + "," + gp.Sid;
        }
    }
    using (var ctx = new Data.DBContext())
    {
        var d2 = (from d in ctx.Set<Entities.Config>()
                  where d.Property == "str"
                  select d).SingleOrDefault();
        d2.Value = Sids;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should help you:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-get-checked-unchecked-nodes-and-its-children-in-kendo-treeview

Comment: Sorry about not being too clear. I need to know how to access the data context for a given node. I am then passing that data to the controller to save the element into the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Send data to controller in Treeview Kendo IU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605338/how-to-send-data-to-controller-in-treeview-kendo-iu)

Answer (score 0):

Using $.post instead of $.ajax fixed the issue.